# PYQT Set different background color for every tab in QTabWidget

Tags: pyqt

I have a QTabWidget with a number of tabs
I want to set the background color of each tab in the tabBar differently.

I can set the text color using: tabBar().setTabTextColor(index, color)
But i want to set the background not the text color.

How can that be done?

Comment: does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/19807893/9501624

Comment: No, it;s talking about the page background. I want to control the tab "button" background

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PyQt4: How to color each tab in QTabWidget separately?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47844741/pyqt4-how-to-color-each-tab-in-qtabwidget-separately)